# adding extra element to a list in terraform if condition is met

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have a list in terraform that looks something like:

```
array = ["a","b","c"]
```

Within this terraform file there are two variables called age and gender, and I want to make it so that the list called array has an extra element called "d" if age is equal to 12 and gender is equal to male (i.e. if var.age == 12 && var.gender == 'male' then array should be ["a","b","c","d"], else array should be ["a","b","c"]). Would the following going along the right path, or would I need to use another method?

```
array = ["a","b","c", var.age == 12 && var.gender == 'male' ? "d" : null]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are few ways you could do it. One way would be (example):

```
variable "array" {
  default = ["a","b","c"]
}

variable "age" {
  default = 12
}

variable "gender" {
  default = "male"
}

locals {
  array = var.age == 12 && var.gender == "male" ? concat(var.array, ["d"]) : var.array
}

output "test" {
  value = local.array
}
```

Comment: Curious... what other ways would be? :)

Comment: I'm getting "The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The 'true' tuple has length 6, but the 'false' tuple has length 5." when trying this

Answer (score 40):

There is another way to do that using [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html):

```
variable = flatten(["a", "b", "c", var.age == 12 ? ["d"] : []])
```

Comment: Made my day -- works for lists of objects too!

Comment: [concat](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/concat) is possibly more appropriate, because it doesn't flatten nested lists.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach to the problem in your particular example is removing empty elements at the end of the array.

`compact` is perhaps the most straightforward, but requires you to rely on using `""` as a sentinel value for `Emptiness`.

[From the documentation:](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/compact)

> `compact` takes a list of strings and returns a new list with any empty string elements removed.

```
> compact(["a", "", "b", "c"])
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
]
```

I would prefer this over the other answers because it's more idiomatic. I suppose it only works for strings though.

```
array = compact(["a","b","c", var.age == 12 && var.gender == 'male' ? "d" : ""])`
["a","b","c"] if age != 12 and gender != male
["a","b","c", "d"] if age == 12 and gender == male
```

Of course the `""` element could be anywhere in your list and `compact` would handle this `optionality` issue.

---

I would also be interested in which has the best `O()` performance. I don't know how `compact` is implemented underneath the hood, but in general you would either copy elements into a new array *or* you would be shifting elements into gaps left by removed elements.

I don't expect any other solution to be much better than this. Perhaps `concat`.

- [`concat` function pulled into terraform source code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/1214a16a6327542206bdc5641d79e5c8761eb49e/internal/lang/functions.go#L55)
- [`concat` source code. Just appends elements into a new slice.](https://github.com/zclconf/go-cty/blob/1712101b2a609156da53405bbf94b0ff7d011e36/cty/function/stdlib/collection.go#L280-L303)

Given that, it probably requires `O(n)` comparisons + appends, and then takes `O(n)` space because a new list is created.

Comment: You could use `null` as sentinel intead of `""`.